# How to trigger a window event during unit testing using vue-test-utils

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I've added 'attachToDocument', but I still can't trigger a keyup event on window.

my dependencies' version:

"@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29"

"vue": "2.5.18"

```
<template lang="pug">
div
  h1 123
</template>
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyup)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', this.handleKeyup)
  },
  methods: {
    handleKeyup() {}
  }
}
</script>
```

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import test from '@/views/test.vue'

describe('just test', () => {
  it('handle keyup', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(test, {
      attachToDocument: true
    })
    const handleKeyup = jest.fn()
    wrapper.setMethods({ handleKeyup })
    wrapper.trigger('keyup')
    expect(handleKeyup).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

'handleKeyup' should have been called.

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You set up your event listener in the `mounted` hook so when you call `wrapper.setMethods` the event listener is already set up with the original empty function. Also `wrapper.trigger` will dispatch the event on the Vue instance but you set up your event listener on the `window` object. Try the following ..

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import test from '@/views/test.vue'

describe('just test', () => {
  it('handle keyup', () => {
    const handleKeyup = jest.fn()
    const wrapper = mount(test, {
        methods: { handleKeyup }
    })
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup'))
    expect(handleKeyup).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Comment: This basically tests if `mounted()` works. What needs to be tested is that the listener attaches to the `window` object, that it gets called on `keyup` and gets removed on beforeDestroy. So [attachToDom](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachtodocument) should probably be used. Another option is to use a `window` mock having `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` as `jest.fn()`s for this test suite.

Answer (score 0):

For if someone need answer for this:

It's method working for me:

First you need register `removeEventListener` of global mode with `defineProperty`

For example:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'removeEventListener', {
    value: jest.fn(),
})
```

After we write the test

```
  it('When beforeMounted is executed', async () => {

    await wrapper.destroy()
    expect(window.removeEventListener).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(window.removeEventListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'keyup',
      wrapper.vm.keyUp
   )
})
```