# How to pass function to a custom hook while writing unit test in Jest/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I have to write a unit test of a custom hook used in **index.js** ([see this implementation](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/react/s/use-unload)) in which I am passing a function as a parameter. I don't know how to pass a function to a hook in unit test. I am a beginner.

How can I achieve a 100% coverage for my unit test?

**useBrowserFwdBackButton.ts** (file in which custom hook is available)

```
import React from 'react';
    
    const useBrowserFwdBackButton = (fn: any) => {
      const cb = React.useRef(fn); // init with fn, so that type checkers won't assume that current might be undefined
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        cb.current = fn;
      }, [fn]);
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        const onForwardBackButtonEvent = (...args: any[]) => cb.current?.(...args);
    
        window.addEventListener('popstate', onForwardBackButtonEvent);
    
        return () => window.removeEventListener('popstate', onForwardBackButtonEvent);
      }, []);
    };
    
    export default useBrowserFwdBackButton;
```

**index.js** (from where hook is calling from functional component)

```
useBrowserFwdBackButton((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (attachmentListLength !== 0) {
      dispatch(deleteGoogleDocument(attachmentList));
    }
  });
```

Comment: Why would you need to store a *function* in `useRef`? (or `useState`, etc)

Comment: I need to create a custom hook thats why created like that.

Comment: Custom hook does not by itself imply *storing a function in a ref*. Please provide detail about *why* you need to store a function in a ref. Especially a ref you never change and don't return.

Comment: i am using this approach. for reference please see link.
https://www.30secondsofcode.org/react/s/use-unload

Comment: My apologies, that looks legit. In the future please include information like that *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jest and `@testing-library/react-hooks` for hook testing

you can creat mock function with `jest.fn()`
eg.

```
const mockFunction = jest.fn();
const { result } = renderHook(() => useBrowserFwdBackButton(mockFunction));
const { .... } = result.current;

// since it's attached to windows event, you need to trigger the "popstate" event

// expects here
expect(mockFunction).toBeCalledTimes(1);
```

additional info (trigger window event) [How to trigger a window event during unit testing using vue-test-utils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738445/how-to-trigger-a-window-event-during-unit-testing-using-vue-test-utils)